# Create postgresql Table in java code

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a code in java that connects with postgreSQL database.

now, I want that when it connects to the database, i will also create database table.

but my problem is that, it will not create the database, and I don't know what is the problem.

here is my code:

```
Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("connect");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
              System.out.println("Could not find the JDBC driver!");
              System.exit(1);
            }
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            //database location, database user, database password
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                           ("jdbc:postgresql:"POS_DB","postgres", "123456");
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String qs = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(user_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,username varchar(225) NOT NULL UNIQUE,password varchar(225),islogged varchar(10))";
            String qs1 = "SELECT * FROM test";
        rs = st.executeQuery(qs);

            System.out.println("connect");
             } catch (SQLException sqle) {
               System.out.println("Could not connect");
               System.exit(1);
             }
```

I am sure that my sql statement in creating the table is correct. but when I run this, it will not create the table. If I replace the string into `select` sql, there is no problem.

does anyone have an idea about my case?

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                       ("jdbc:postgresql:"POS_DB","postgres", "123456");
```

is invalid.

You have a `"` before POS_DB that should'nt be here.

Too see some example check the [documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html).

Answer (score 5):

you probably want to use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like so:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(user_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,username varchar(225) NOT NULL UNIQUE,password varchar(225),islogged varchar(10))");
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

You need *executeUpdate* for DML and DDL statements.

Also, make sure your DDL statement is correct, i don't know the exact "if not exists" syntax for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

postgresql 10 - 'user' is a keyword, thus not a good choice for a table. You will need a name that is not a reserved word.