# How execute \d tablename using Java and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, cmd

How do I execute `\d tablename` using Java and PostgreSQL?

```java
PreparedStatement pst = jdbc.conn.prepareStatement("\d u_item");
ResultSet set = pst.executeQuery();
```

Error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
```

Comment: Can it be executed ‘\d tablename’ sql use java?

Comment: `"\\d u_item"` If you want a backslash in your statement, it needs to be escaped with another one.

Comment: I allready use "\\d u_item" execute

Comment: still ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"

Comment: Why do you try to do this? What do you *really* want to do? Your question looks like a [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I want to use java query create table sentence for example CREATE TABLE "public"."test" ( "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass), "name" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default", CONSTRAINT "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") ) ; ALTER TABLE "public"."test" OWNER TO "postgres"

Comment: still ERROR: syntax error at or near "describe"

Comment: describe tablename is about mysql,not is postgresql

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is a command of the interactive [`psql` client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). It is *not* part of SQL.

You can't execute this command over a JDBC connection.

Comment: can use java query create table sentence?

Comment: for example: result
CREATE TABLE "public"."test" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
  "name" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  CONSTRAINT "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
;

ALTER TABLE "public"."test" 
  OWNER TO "postgres";

Answer (score 2):

You can also obtain table meta data Using Postgres java driver.

```
String tableName = "u_item";
ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName.toLowerCase(), null))
```

Table name is converted to lowercase when Postgres stores its name in the system catalog.

[updated] have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626870/create-postgresql-table-in-java-code)

Comment: I want result CREATE TABLE "public"."test" ( "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass), "name" varchar(255) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default", CONSTRAINT "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") ) ; ALTER TABLE "public"."test" OWNER TO "postgres";

Comment: I want query create table ,not is add create table

Comment: you may need to do some manipulation when you obtain result from PgResultSetMetaData